# Visual Studio 2015 : thousands of spurious build errors

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm on a largish solution, with 20 C# projects. These last three days every few hours, a build will generate 20 000 or so spurious missing-type-or-namespace errors. I've missing references to everything. I can get them to go away sometimes by building the projects one at a time, but I need a more durable solution. The operation that may have unleashed this wave of weirdness was updating all nuget packages for the solution. (The missing references are to solution projects, not external packages.) I've committed everything since the nuget update, and all other team members and the build server are compiling happily. I don't even know where to start looking to fix this???

Comment: I had funny issues with updating nuget packages in connection with whether or not the solution was created with the "create subfolder for project" tick set. When funny things happen, it's sometimes enough to "Clean" the solution, exit the studio and open it again. If that doesn't help, try opening the `prj` files with a text editor and manually fixing the references - they are probably one nesting level off.

Comment: I love that word, Spurious :)

Answer (score 1):

The packages are probably still referenced in your sln but don't exist. Delete all the packages for the solution via the NuGet package manager then repull the packages.config and run `nuget restore` should reinstall the dependencies and ensure your sln is in sync with your packages and vice versa. If that doesn't work maybe clone your colleagues packages directory and `.sln`. Finally, ensure you're packages directory is in your `.gitignore` so it doesn't get pushed up and subsequently come out of sync with your colleagues.